# Energy integral: how does $p∇^2 p$ become $∇(p∇p)−(∇p)^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Given the energy integral:
$E(u) = \frac{1}{2}\int_V (e_t^2) dV$

$e_t = \nabla \cdot(D \nabla e)$

Differentiating this integral w.r.t. time yields the below:
$
 \frac{dE}{dt} = \int_V ee_t dV = \int_V e \nabla \cdot(D\nabla e) dV = \int_V \nabla \cdot(e D\nabla e) dV - \int_V \nabla e \cdot( D\nabla e) dV 
$

I don't understand the relation on both sides of the last equal sign on the last line: in other words how does the following general relation hold:
$p \nabla ^2 p  = \nabla (p \nabla p) - (\nabla p)^2$

Comment: From the expression I don't see how $e_t$ is related to $t$. Can you provide more context?

Comment: e represents energy, and energy might change or not change depending on time. So subindex t indicates the partial derivative w.r.t. time.

Thx guys that really helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last equal sign is just the product rule, we have 
$$ \def\div{\mathop{\rm div}}\def\grad{\mathop{\rm grad}}\div (eD\grad e) 
  = e \div(D\grad e) + \grad e \cdot D\grad e  
$$ 
hence 
$$ e\div(D \grad e) = \div(eD\grad e) - \grad e \cdot D \grad e $$

---

Addendum: For the simplified version with $p$, it's the same, we have 
$$ \div(p \grad p) = \grad p \cdot \grad p + p \div\grad p \iff p \div\grad p = \div(p\grad p) - \grad p \cdot \grad p $$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\nabla (fg)=f\nabla g+g\nabla f$$